# No internet connectivity on Fresh Windows 10 Installation

Tags: windows, internet

I installed Windows 10 Pro by using the Media Creation Tool provided by Microsoft.

The installation went on without a hitch. But now I can't access internet through my web browsers.

Weird thing is, it worked for a while and then I downloaded Google Chrome and now no browser (Chrome/Edge/IE) can access the internet. But, other apps like Spotify or Windows Store apps work fine. Even the Windows Updates are working in the background.

What's causing this?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: Sounds like a proxy server to me. Check Start -> Proxy Settings (and disable the auto-setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browsers are configured to use a proxy server.

From a command shell, ping Google DNS servers continuously while troubleshooting the connectivity:

ping -t -l 0 8.8.8.8

Verify the system successfully pings the host before configuring network proxies.

Access the proxy settings from IE, Edge or the Internet Options in the Control Panel, choose Direct Connection while monitoring the PING window and retry your browser(s).